# Replacing CString in mingw compiler for eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have some code which is relatively big, but there is one part of it which uses something called `CString` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) . Right now I am using the mingw compiler on eclipse and it doesnt seem to recognize it which makes sense. But I need to use the other part of the code. I know I can replace the CString with a const char * but there are several function like append which the code uses which are not defined. I was wondering whats the best way to port this code? Also there are other stdafx.h dependencies also like _T(). Whats the best approach I should take now?

Answer (score 0):

There is a CString replacement over on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1146/CString-clone-Using-Standard-C). I just googled for "CString alternative". I haven't looked at it but it should be easier to use that instead of `std::string`.